# Verification for finding the cdf from pmf

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

If I have the pmf of a random variable X such that:
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if } x=0 \\ 0, & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases} $$
Would the cdf just be the same as the pmf. Such that:
$$ F(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if } x=0 \\ 0, & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases} $$
where $f(x)$ is the pmf, and $F(x)$ is the cdf. 
I figured this was to simple to actually be true which is why I am asking. Because in my class and in the textbook it only ever does examples with multiple cases or a bigger range for its values.

Comment: The "c" in "cdf" stands for "cumulative", so no that's not how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The cdf $F(x)$ "cumulates" all pmf values $f(t)$ for $t\le x$ :

$$F(x)=\sum_{t\le x}f(t)=
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{ if } x<0\\
1,  & \text{ if } x\ge 0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Oh ok thank you for your help, I know thats what we did for pmf's with multiple values, and more then one x values, so I wasn't 100% sure if it would still be the same because there was only one x value and f(x) value.